# Why does sage treat local python variables as global?

Tags: python, function, sage

New to sage and python, so I'm not sure which I'm abusing. I'm trying to define the following function which acts on the input list A, but every time I input the function affects the global value of A. How can I make it behave locally?

```
def listxgcd( A ):
    g,s,t=xgcd(A.pop(0),A.pop(0))
    coeffs=[s,t]
    while a!=[]:
        g,s,t=xgcd(g,A.pop(0))
        coeffs=[s*i for i in coeffs]
        coeffs=coeffs+[t]
    return coeffs
```

I've tried setting `B=A` and substituting B everywhere but this doesn't work either which I don't understand. Do I need to declare some sort of sage-y variable thing?

```
def listxgcd( a ):
    B=a
    g,s,t=xgcd(B.pop(0),B.pop(0))
    coeffs=[s,t]
    while B!=[]:
        g,s,t=xgcd(g,B.pop(0))
        coeffs=[s*i for i in coeffs]
        coeffs=coeffs+[t]
    return coeffs
```

Much thanks!

Comment: the answer here is very useful 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/python-how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a reference to a container object to your `listxgcd` function and the function retrieves elements from that container using `pop`. This is not a scope issue, simply the fact there you are operating directly on the container you have passed to the function.

If you don't want the function to modify the container, make a copy of it:

```
import copy
def listxgcd( Ain ):
    A = copy(Ain)
    ...
```

Or better, access the elements using indexing, if the container allows it:

```
...
g,s,t=xgcd(A[0],A[1])
...
for i in range(2,len(A)):
    g,s,t=xgcd(g,A[i])
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks isedev! I end up having to use the syntax copy.copy(Ain)

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with Sage. This is the normal Python behavior. The only modification Sage does on Python behavior is [preparsing](http://www.sagemath.org/doc/reference/misc/sage/misc/preparser.html) when you are using command interpreter (no preparse is done when importing a Python file).

Comment: @hivert that's right, I should have made that explicit.